# string slicing python in lists

Tags: python, string, list, slice

maybe this is a dublicate but I'm not finding an answer.
How do I manage to slice a long string after every comma that it turns like a list
like this :

```
st=  input("Enter string:").slice(',')
```

I enter a string like this "Jezus, Santa Maria, Program , Hangover"
I want to slice it to `['Jezus','Santa Maria','Program','Hangover']`
and then use `st[1]` as Santa maria 
but when I try to print `st[1]` it comes out only 'e'
I want that it comes out Santa Maria.
Any help?
Using python 3.3 Windows

Comment: This is not your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, slice is not a method for the [str](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) object. You should use [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). On a side note, please refrain from naming variable to a built-in or from standard library.

```
string=  input("Enter string:").slice(',')
```

change to

```
st=  input("Enter string:").split(',')
```

Demo

```
>>> st=  input("Enter string:").split(',')
Enter string:"Jezus, Santa Maria, Program , Hangover"
>>> st[1]
' Santa Maria'
```

Comment: Yes, I know I just used the bad name :)

Comment: Although, using the name `string` is a lot less troublesome in python 3.x compared to python2.x since most of the useful stuff is moved onto the `str` type ...

Comment: Atleast use `s` instead of `st`, not everyone will instantly realize `st` means `string`. Just like `f` and `d` stand for `float` and `double`, `s` stands for `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`:

```
>>> "Jezus, Santa Maria, Program , Hangover".split(', ')
['Jezus', 'Santa Maria', 'Program ', 'Hangover']
```

Note that your words are separated not just by a comma, but by a comma with a space.

Comment: I know but string[1] gives 'e' and not Santa Maria

Comment: `string[1]` is `e`, `string.split(', ')[1]` is Santa Maria. There's no `slice` method. Is your actual code something like `string = input(); string.split()`?

Comment: @KillerB: You need to do `lst = string.split(', ')`, and then `lst[1]`. Doing `string.split(', ')` doesn't actually change the `string` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code doesn't do nothing with `string`. You actually need to generate a new object from `string`, which is a list of substrings, using the `split` method.

My approach would be:

```
substrings = [s.strip() for s in yourstring.split(',')]
```

That would divide the string with the comma as separator, and add the STRIPPED substring to the list (thus removing any white space).

You then could do:

```
> substrings[0]
>> 'Jezus'
```